# How to resolve Maven dependency

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, dependencies

I want to use the version mongodb:bson:3.8.0

When I run this project in IDE (Intellij), It used bson:3.8.0

However, when I build it with the command:

```
mvn clean install
```

It will run with another version: org.mongodb:bson:3.3.0

This is dependencies tree:

```
+-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  +-org.mongodb:bson:3.8.0
and
+-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  +-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    +-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      +-org.mongodb:bson:3.3.0
and
+-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  +-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    +-org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-async:3.3.0
      +-org.mongodb:bson:3.3.0
and
+-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  +-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    +-org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-async:3.3.0
      +-org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:3.3.0
        +-org.mongodb:bson:3.3.0
```

And when I show the path of Bson lib, I had the results:

- When I run in IDE: **../org/mongodb/bson/3.8.0/bson-3.8.0.jar**
- When I run after I build with mvn command: **../app/lib/mongo-java-
  driver-3.3.0.jar**

Answer (score 0):

To force maven to use version `3.8.0`, you should explicitly declare a dependency on `org.mongodb:bson:3.8.0` in your won pom directly.

This direct dependency will supersede other versions included as transitive dependencies.

Alternatively, you will need to add exclusions for `org.mongodb:bson` on all dependencies that pull version `3.3.0`

Comment: I also explicitly declare a dependency on my pom file.
But it still not work

Comment: @TatHuan No way. Please post the actual content of your pom file, as that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Sorry, this is a private project. So I can't post all of dependencies.


When I print the path of Bson lib, I had the results:


When I run in IDE: ../org/mongodb/bson/3.8.0/bson-3.8.0.jar


When I run after I build with mvn command: ../app/lib/mongo-java- driver-3.3.0.jar

Comment: In that case there's no way to tell. As far as I know, declaring the dependency directly in this pom will override transitive dependencies. You could try `mvn dependency:tree` to see where it's coming from. But it's also possible that your problem is with the packaging or something else. Is this a `war` artifact?

Comment: Thank @ermest_k
I will re-check